# Bypass SWT Browser Authorization Dialog

Tags: java, browser, authorization, swt

I have an application that prints the contents of a URL (to a physical printer) at a certain point. I want this to happen automatically and without further user input. I am using SWT to load the URL into an SWT browser (that works int he background only - it is not visible) and print. The sole problem at this point is that the server wants to authorize me, popping up a dialog for a username/password. I've been able to get around this by putting the credentials in the URL (http://username:password@server.com/resource) but I imagine there must be a better way to do this.

For clarification, this is an *authorization* dialog, not an *authentication* dialog. I am aware of addAuthenticationListener, but this is never called since I am trying to *authorize*, not *authenticate*.

Comment: Is that last paragraph right? It seems like you flipped something somewhere: "this is an *authentication* dialog ... I am trying to *authorize*, not *authenticate* "

Comment: er yeah, got them backwards, will fix. Just goes to show how tricky it can be to keep them straight when looking for answers since they sound so much alike.